# Using SUMIF Function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to calculate Datafame value with Pandas.

But I couldn't calculate "FW_result" and "SS_result".

```
df1:
category  num  standard
  FW      U-1    3
  FW      U-2    3
  FW      U-3    2
  SS      U-4    3
  SS      U-5    2


df2:
name    U-1 U-2 U-3 U-4 U-5
 A       3   1   1   2   1
 B       2   3   2   1   2
 C       2   2   2   3   1


The desired result would be: 

name    U-1 U-2 U-3 U-4 U-5 FW_result   SS_Result
 A       3   1   1   2   1     *(63%)       #(60%)
 B       2   3   2   1   2     **(88%)      ##(60%)
 C       2   2   2   3   1     ***(75%)     ###(80%)
```

I want to fill the * and # values.
The FW_result refers to df1 So, `(df2 value)/(standard sum)`

Example *:

```
(3+1+1)/(3+3+2) =>63%
```

Example #:

```
(2+1) /(3+2)   => 60%
```

and I want to express the result to %(persent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `nums` don't overlap in categories you can use this.

You can use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) here, then use use [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html), then divide those values using [`df.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) and multiply with 100 to get percentage values using [`df.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) to get desired results.

```
g = df1.groupby('category')['standard'].sum()
m = df2.groupby(df2.columns.map(df1.set_index('num')['category']),axis=1).sum()
               # Mapping to convert U-1 to FW, U-2 to FW based on df1
               # If you know it's always the order as df1 then you can simply
               #_.groupby.(df1['category'].tolist(), axis=1)

df2[['FW_res', 'SS_res']] = m.div(g).mul(100)
```

If they overlap then try this.

```
df1
#  category  num  standard
#0       FW  U-1         3
#1       FW  U-2         3
#2       FW  U-3         2
#3       SS  U-4         3
#4       SS  U-5         2
#5       SS  U-1         4
p = df1.pivot_table(index='category', columns='num', values='standard', aggfunc='sum')
p
#num       U-1  U-2  U-3  U-4  U-5
#category
#FW        3.0  3.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
#SS        4.0  NaN  NaN  3.0  2.0

# Now, little bit of Numpy boardcasting.
#df2.se_index('name') # if index is not name else ignore this step.
vs = np.nansum(df2.values[:,None]+p.values, axis=-1)
v = p.sum(axis=1).values
out = (vs - v) / v
df2[['FW_res', 'SS_res']] = pd.DataFrame(out*100, index=df2.index)
```

Comment: hmmm, this failed if overlapping, e.g. add `SS      U-1    2` to `df1`

Comment: No, only mentioned i in start of answer like me.

Comment: @jezrael Added for overlapping values too.

Comment: Seems answer was accepting before, so no overlaping values.

Answer (score 2):

For general solution also with overlapping values in `num` for both new columns use:

Idea is filter `df1` for `fw` and `ss` values, then use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by `num` values, sum and divide by sum of original `standard` columns:

```
df3 = df1.groupby('category').agg({'num':list, 'standard':'sum'})
print (df3)
                      num  standard
category                           
FW        [U-1, U-2, U-3]         8
SS             [U-4, U-5]         5

for col in df3.index:
    df2[f'{col}_result'] = (df2.reindex(df3.loc[col, 'num'], axis=1).sum(axis=1)
                               .div(df3.loc[col, 'standard']).mul(100))
print (df2)
  name  U-1  U-2  U-3  U-4  U-5  FW_result  SS_result
0    A    3    1    1    2    1       62.5       60.0
1    B    2    3    2    1    2       87.5       60.0
2    C    2    2    2    3    1       75.0       80.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a combination of `melt`, `merge` and `groupby` to reshape the data and get the sums :

```
df2[['FW_result', 'SS_result']] = (df1.merge(df2.melt("name", var_name="num"), on="num")
                                   .assign(num=lambda x: x.num.str[0])
                                   .groupby(["name", "category", "num"])
                                   .pipe(lambda x: x.value.sum() / x.standard.sum())
                                   .mul(100)
                                   .unstack("category").to_numpy())


  name  U-1 U-2 U-3 U-4 U-5 FW_result   SS_result
0   A   3   1   1   2   1   62.5        60.0
1   B   2   3   2   1   2   87.5        60.0
2   C   2   2   2   3   1   75.0        80.0
```